# How to define the columns in CRUD grid?

Tags: vaadin, crud

I need to define which columns shall appear and their order in the CRUD grid.

1. If I use `crud.getGrid().setColumns(...)` then the edit column does not appear. If I include `vaadin-crud-edit-column` in the list then I get an exception cause this column does not exist (but I see it there!).
2. If I remove the un-needed columns (lot of trouble anyway!) I still can't change the column sequence.

Is there some way to sort this out?

Comment: first remove all and then add the one you need? Otherwise you would have to show the code and the version of Vaadin you are using.

Comment: Are you using Vaadin's Enhanced Crud component, Crud UI Add-on, or something else?

Comment: Yep I am using the Enhanced CRUD and No removing all columns does not work since it does remove also the vaadin-crud-edit-column (and you have no way to filter it out since it has a special treatment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding edit column to the Grid in Crud there is a helper method `Crud.addEditColumn(grid)` You can also use this method to add your edit column as a first column or last column depending how you configure the Grid.

```
private void customGrid() {
    Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>(Person.class);
    Crud<Person> crud = new Crud<>(Person.class, grid, createPersonEditor());

    PersonDataProvider dataProvider = new PersonDataProvider();
    crud.setDataProvider(dataProvider);

    grid.setColumns("firstName","lastName");
    Crud.addEditColumn(grid);

    add(crud);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: Compiles, executes with no exceptions, but all cells are blank.

Comment: That is odd, works for me, see the picture

Comment: Yes, this way works, I was reusing the provided grid instead of passing it as argument to constructor. Thank you very much.